# symfony2 route pattern

Tags: design-patterns, symfony, routes

This pattern:

```
pattern:  /Messages/.{_format}
```

Not working when i go to url /Messages

I want to redirect me to the /Messages/ like without the {_format} at the end of the pattern.

HOW?

Comment: Have you tried setting the default to `null`?

Comment: hm.. how you mean it? format? Like defaults: { _controller: "MessagesBundle:Default:index",_format: null } ??

Comment: yep, that's what I meant!

Answer (score 6):

It's not working because by `/Messages` you are calling not defined pattern. I suppose that problem is with `/.`. Instead that you should try something like that:

```
messages_show:
    pattern:  /Messages.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Messages:show, _format: html }
requirements:
    _format:  html|rss
```

Btw. current Symfony2 routing documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: no, my pattern is fine .. everything works... but my problem is : when i would pattern just like /messages/ and visitor would come to url "/messages" he would be redirected to "/messages/" ... this is why i want somehow the backslash at the end of the pattern ... just dont know how to do it with _format at the end.